# Booting Windows from UEFI

Tags: boot, 20.04, uefi, windows-10

I have a Dell Precision M4800 laptop. It is dual boot system - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and MS Windows10.

After I did the latest Windows update, the computer will only boot into Ubuntu without showing the usual Windows boot menu.
I've run Boot Info on site https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and the result is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4ds6gKb9cM and according to the advice I am looking for help here.
I will be grateful for  the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: You have two drives each with an ESP and boot entries. Can you not boot Windows directly from UEFI using UEFI boot menu f12 when you boot?